# akka java tcp chatroom

Tags: java, tcp, akka

I tried to extend the code about TCP in doc to make a simple chat room, simply put, several clients connected to server, one client send a string, server broadcast the string to all clients...the code I wrote showed below, it doesn't work, can someone tell why?

the program behave wrong, say 2 clients connected to server, one send a message, then the sender get 2 messages back, the other get nothing...

Main.java

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    akka.Main.main(new String[] { Server.class.getName()});
  }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server extends UntypedActor {

  final ActorRef manager = Tcp.get(getContext().system()).manager();

  public static Props props(ActorRef manager) {
    return Props.create(Server.class, manager);
  }

  @Override
  public void preStart() throws Exception {
    final ActorRef tcp = Tcp.get(getContext().system()).manager();
    tcp.tell(TcpMessage.bind(getSelf(), new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 8888), 100), getSelf());
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof Bound) {
      manager.tell(msg, getSelf());

    } else if (msg instanceof CommandFailed) {
      getContext().stop(getSelf());

    } else if (msg instanceof Connected) {
      final Connected conn = (Connected) msg;
      manager.tell(conn, getSelf());
      final ActorRef handler = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SimplisticHandler.class));
      getContext().system().eventStream().subscribe(handler, Notification.class);
      getSender().tell(TcpMessage.register(handler), getSelf());
    }
  }

}
```

SimplisticHandler.java

```
public class SimplisticHandler extends UntypedActor {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof Received) {

      final ByteString data = ((Received) msg).data();
      System.out.println(data);
      getContext().system().eventStream().publish(new Notification(getSender(), getSelf(), 1, data));

    } else if (msg instanceof ConnectionClosed) {

      getContext().stop(getSelf());

    } else if (msg instanceof Notification) {

      Notification noti = (Notification)msg;
      // TODO while the below statement don't broadcast ?
      if (noti.id == 1) 
        noti.sender.tell(TcpMessage.write((ByteString)(noti.obj)), getSelf());

    }
  }
}
```

Notification.java

```
public class Notification {
    public final ActorRef sender;
    public final ActorRef receiver;
    public final int id;
    public final Object obj;

    public Notification(ActorRef sender, ActorRef receiver, int id, Object obj) {
      this.sender = sender;
      this.receiver = receiver;
      this.id = id;
      this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind giving more details about why it doesn't work? (error message, wrong behavior, etc.).

Comment: the program behave wrong, say 2 clients connected to server, one send a message, then the sender get 2 messages back, the other get nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned `Notification.sender` with the tcp actor who send the message.

What you need to do is pass the sender to `SimplisticHandler` while handling `Connected` in `Server`. And every `SimplisticHandler` always write to their own tcp actor.